# JavaFXGL how to get the library for java from maven

Tags: java

I am trying to use the javaFXGL library.  Which is the java gaming library.  I am not sure how to use maven to download the library to eclipse.  Does anyone know a step by step way to download this.  I need to this get some example code running.

Answer (score 1):

I would be easier to get the help if you add your `code` in the question along with the problems/errors you are facing. Anyways I would suggest you to first read [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html) and [this](https://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) to understand what is `maven` and how it works with `Eclipse IDE`.

After reading the articles you will understand that maven project has `pom.xml` file which is used for maven settings or you can say for Dependency Management, Build Management, etc.

To add the `library` you need to add its maven dependency in the `pom.xml` inside the `<dependencies>` tag like below:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.almasb/fxgl -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.almasb</groupId>
    <artifactId>fxgl</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also find other dependencies on [www.mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com)